# Are n_estimators and n_features same?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use RandomForestClassifier with 67 features and 3000 samples. Does setting the 'n_estimators=30' uses only 30 features outof 67 featuring during fitting?

```
  RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `RandomForest` is a bagging approach to reduce the variance of a set of low-bias-high-variance classifiers (usually `DecisionTree` classifier as default). Here `n_estimator` refers to how many such 'over-fitting' classifiers are used in the majority voting system.

Also, in `RandomForest` setting, it is typically recommended to set `max_depth` to a quite large value to ensure each classifier indeed has low-bias property.